# Sistematic sampling rewritting the variance

Tags: sampling, sampling-theory

If $N = n \cdot a $ where $a$ is an integer, show that the variance $V_{SY}(\hat{t}_\pi)$ given by
$$ V_{SY}(\hat{t}_\pi) = N^2 \dfrac{1}{a} \sum_{r=1}^{a} \left( \bar{y}_{Sr} - \bar{y}_U\right)^2 $$
with $\bar{y}_U = \sum_U y_k/N$ which is the population mean, can be written as
$$ V_{SY}(\hat{t}_\pi) = \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{r=1}^{a} \sum_{r^{\prime}=1}^{a} \left( t_{Sr} - t_{Sr^{\prime}}\right)^2$$
where $t_{Sr} = \sum_{Sr} y_k $

Would someone be so kind of giving me a Hint?, I think I'm overthinking it and it's more simple than it looks, the exercise is from Model Assited Survey Sampling-Snärdal,ex 3.24

Comment: You have many undefined symbols e.g. $\hat{t_{\pi}}$.

Comment: The claim is $$N^2 \dfrac{1}{a} \sum_{r=1}^{a} \left( \bar{y}_{S_r} - \bar{y}_U\right)^2=\dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{r=1}^{a} \sum_{r^{\prime}=1}^{a} \left( t_{S_r} - t_{S_{r^{\prime}}}\right)^2$$
where $N=n\,a,\ \bar{y}_{S_r}={1\over n}t_{S_r},\ \bar{y}_U={1\over N}\sum_{r^{\prime}=1}^{a}t_{S_{r^{\prime}}}.$ Here $t_{S_r}$ is the sum of elements in $S_r$ (the $r$th possible systematic sample, population $U$ being the disjoint union of the $S_r$). Plug these def's into the LHS and expand the square, expand the square also on the RHS, then apply the summations to the results on both sides, and voilà.

Comment: Your question is lacking some context and relevant definitions (such as those in my previous comment). It would help to explain that here a population $U$ of size $N$ is being sampled systematically in such a way that $U$ is partitioned into disjoint sets $S_1,\ldots,S_a,$ each of which has size $n$ (so $N=n\,a$), and that the systematic sample is one of these $a$ sets selected uniformly at random. (If $S_r$ is the sample, then $\hat{t}_\pi=N\,\bar{y}_{S_r}$ is an estimator of the population total $t_U.$)